# How I solve the runtim error coming while running the MNIST datasets in pycharm

Tags: dataset, sklearn-pandas

RuntimeWarning: Invalid cache, redownloading file warn("Invalid cache, redownloading file", RuntimeWarning)

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning message, you can retry to fix it